# Force Hide keyboard in iPad Safari

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, html

I have a form in the order;

1. Textbox
2. Dropdown

Now when user moves focus from textbox to dropdown, the keyboard still remains and it kind of hides the dropdown options...

How do I make the keyboard hide (onblur of textbox)

I have already tried window.blur and it does not work.

Please help me. thank you.

Comment: This is a question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to focus() on a non-text element.

or

```
$("#yourTextField").blur(); //jquery
```